# CheckMultiSelect - Dojo

Tags: dojo

```
 <input data-dojo-type="dijit.form.FilteringSelect"    
            data-dojo-props="name: 'jobSelect', store:Practiv.Q.jobStore, searchAttr:'JobNumber'"   
            id="jobIdSelect"  />
```

Currently the above code displays a drop down with items that can be selected. I currently want to add a checkbox to the drop down list. I have replaced it with the code below.

```
<select data-dojo-type="dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect"  
            data-dojo-props="name: 'jobSelect', store:Practiv.Q.jobStore, searchAttr:'JobNumber'"   
            id="jobIdSelect" ></select>
```

Unfortunately it doesnt work. Any suggestions?

Comment: [These](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605973/multiselectcombobox-issue-in-dojo) answers of mine may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

instead of setting store in data-dojo-props set like this :-

```
<select data-dojo-type="dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect"  store="Practiv.Q.jobStore" 
            data-dojo-props="name: 'jobSelect', searchAttr:'JobNumber'"   
            id="jobIdSelect" ></select>
```

first you have ensure that your store is connected to CheckMultiSelect.