# Adjust sorting of multiselectcombo box in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a question similar to this one:
[MultiSelectCombobox issue in dojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605973/multiselectcombobox-issue-in-dojo)

However, I have changed the selection values in the list and they are not showing up in the order I want them.

This is how I have them in the code:

```
            var memoryStore = new Memory({
            idProperty: "value",
            data: [
                {value: "VI", label: "Vehicle Info"},
                {value: "PP", label: "PartsPro"},
                {value: "PC", label: "eParts Catalog"},
                {value: "EZ", label: "EZ Wiring"},
                {value: "DD", label: "DDCSN"},
                {value: "SL", label: "Service Link"},
                {value: "QC", label: "Quick Claim"}
            ]
        });
```

This is how they show up when page is rendered:

[image]

I need to have the options show up in the order I placed them in the code.

Also, is there a way that I can set 'Vehicle Info' to be selected when the page loads?

EDIT:

I have figured out how to get a default checkbox selected:

```
var checkedMultiSelect = new MyCheckedMultiSelect ({
            dropDown: true,
            multiple: true,
            label: "Select something...",
            store: dataStore
        }, "placeholder");

        checkedMultiSelect.startup();

        checkedMultiSelect.set("value", ["VI"]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to not use a store at all. Instead use the "private" method _addOptionItem :

```
require([
    "dojo/_base/array",
    "dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(array, CheckedMultiSelect) {
    var options = [
        {value: "VI", label: "Vehicle Info", selected : "selected" },
        {value: "PP", label: "PartsPro"},
        {value: "PC", label: "eParts Catalog"},
        {value: "EZ", label: "EZ Wiring"},
        {value: "DD", label: "DDCSN"},
        {value: "SL", label: "Service Link"},
        {value: "QC", label: "Quick Claim"}
    ];

    var select = new CheckedMultiSelect({
        dropDown: true,
        multiple: true,
        label: "Select something..."
    }, "list");

    select.startup();

    array.forEach(options, function(option) {
        select._addOptionItem(option);
    });

    select._updateSelection();
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/bh6r9vo0/

Comment: This works with a caveat. Now the default checked 'Vehicle Info' broke again.